# Caffe installation on Ubuntu 14.04. Stuck in last step

Tags: python, ubuntu, deep-learning, caffe

I have struggled with Caffe for two days, and always stuck at the 'make test' step.
For detail, please look the code.

```
  LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3
  /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libglog.a(libglog_la-logging.o): relocation  R_X86_64_32S against `_ZTVN6google4base6LoggerE' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
  /usr/local/lib/libglog.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
```

I'm new to this and can't really figure out what should I do.
Is there anyone have encountered this issue? Please help me to fix this issue. Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: It's good that you've included the detail of your error.  I think you should also include the code you are trying to compile.  Also please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am trying to install caffe on Ubuntu 14. This error happened at nearly last step of my installation.

Comment: Before that, I installed cuda, cudnn and python2.7. After the tying 'make all -j4 ' this error pop up on t he screen.